# Turing machine decides languages in RE

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Given this language:
$$L_{s_1,s_2} = \{ \langle M_1 \rangle \langle M_2 \rangle | L(M_1) \in S_1 \text{ and } L(M_2) \in S_2 \}$$
I want to prove that for $S_1=RE$ and  $S_2=RE$, then $L_{S_1,S_2} \in R$.

The way I started was by trying to build a Turing Machine that decides $L_{S_1,S_2}$:

**Let $M_{12}$ be that Turing machine.**

1. For each input word $w$:
2. If $w$ cannot be decoded as $\langle M_1 \rangle \langle M_2 \rangle$ then halt and reject.
3. Run $w$ on both $M_1$ and $M_2$.
4. If one of the two machines above halted, then $M_{12}$ halts and accepts $w$.

**And here I got stuck:**

What if the two machines didn't stop over $w$? how should I halt and reject $w$ in $M_{12}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, for every Turing machine $M$, $L(M) \in \mathsf{RE}$. Therefore your language can be rewritten as
$$
\{ \langle M_1 \rangle \langle M_2 \rangle : M_1,M_2 \text{ Turing machines} \}.
$$
This obviates some of the steps in your oddly named machine $M_{12}$.

Comment: there are machines where L(M)∈co-RE. but still, if you have an input that could be interpreted as $M_1$ and $M_2$ how can you check that the language of each machine is in $RE$?

Comment: That fact that the language of some Turing machines belongs to coRE in no way contradicts the fact that the language of *every* Turing machine is in RE.

Comment: i still don't understand why every TM $M$ the language it accepts (i.e. $L(M)$) must be in $RE$?
Since there are languages which are not in $RE$, for instance $L_{EQ}=\{ <M_1><M_2>|L(M_1)=L(M_2) \}$ and the fact that there are some TM that accepts $L_{EQ}$, does not make $L_{EQ} \in RE$.

Comment: The point is that there is *no* Turing machine that accepts $L_{EQ}$. However, RE is *defined* as the set of languages accepted (through halting) by Turing machines.